# Сделать один AJAX запрос к серверу вместо многих

Tags: php, html, ajax

Настраиваю рейтинг "сердечком" со счетчиком кликов (примерно как в твиттере).
Сторона клиента выглядит так:

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post(
            'ratings.php',
            out_data,
            function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data('fsr', INFO);
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        );
    });

    $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles the mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },
        // Handles the mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
            // can't use 'this' because it wont contain the updated data
            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );

    // This actually records the vote
    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
            'ratings.php',
            clicked_data,
            function(INFO) {
                widget.data('fsr', INFO);
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            'json'
        ); 
    });
});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').total_points;

    if (votes > 0) {
        $(widget).find('.star_1').andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    }
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text(votes);
}
// END FIRST THING    
</script>
```

Когда просто нажимаешь на сердечки, все происходит нормально.
Но в начале, при первичной загрузке состояний сердечек и счетчиков - тормоза.
Объектов с классом .rate_widget довольно много, это порождает большое количество запросов и занимает много времени.

Как собрать все запросы в один, потом их пачкой обработать на сервере, вернуть сюда и разложить по местам?

Вот весь серверсайд (ratings.php):

```
<?php
$rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);
isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();

class ratings {
var $data_file = './ratings.data.txt';
private $widget_id;
private $data = array();

function __construct($wid) {
$this->widget_id = $wid;
$all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);
if($all) {
    $this->data = unserialize($all);
}
}

public function get_ratings() {
if($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
    echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
}
else {
    $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
    $data['total_points'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($data);
} 
}

public function vote() {
$ID = $this->widget_id;
if($this->data[$ID]) {
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += 1;
}
else {
    $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = 1;
}

file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
$this->get_ratings();
}
}
```

Comment: А почему состояние нельзя выводит при формировании самой страницы не прибегая к js тут же после загрузки?

Comment: Хороший вопрос... Я так и сделаю!

Comment: Раз уж писал ответ на вопрос, то коротко - формируете массив из ид сердечек, отправляете скрипту (в виде json к примеру), в php формируете массив с id сердечек и нужной вам информацией, отправляете обратно ввиду json. В js циклом приходитесь по ответу от php, по ид находите сердечко, и выполняете нужные действия. Но в любом случае ничего хорошего от долгих циклов.

Comment: Дружище, пожалуйста, напиши хотя-бы набросок кода...
Я сам не справлюсь.

Было принято решение все-таки делать цикл и AJAX для первичного формирования страницы (Это - более структурно, да и потом пригодится).

Comment: Все. Не надо. Я справился.

Comment: Лучше обрабатывать на стороне сервера при выводе, конкретно в данном случае :)